# Homeomorphism of coarser topologies

Tags: general-topology

It seems to me that if two topologies, $t1$ and $t2$ are homeomorphic, then any coarser topology $t1' \subset t1$ must be homeomorphic to some coarser topology $t2' \subset t2$, and vice versa. This would seem to follow since the collections of sets involved must already be contained the homeomorphism. However, I have not been able to find any authoritative statement to this effect. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $X$ is a set and $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on $X$ such that $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(X,\tau_2)$ are homeomorphic, let $f\colon X\longrightarrow X$ be such a homeomorphism. Then, if $\tau_1'$ is a topology on $X$ which is coarser than $\tau_1$, then, if $\tau_2'=\{f(A)\mid A\in\tau_1'\}$, $\tau_2'$ is a topology on $X$ which is coarser than $\tau_2$ and $(X,\tau_1')$ and $(X,\tau_2')$ are homeomorphic (again, take $f$).